# How to set font size and font of my text within a function in TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not sure what is wrong with me but I can't seem to figure out how to set the font size of my text within my "instructions" function.

```
import random
import time


num = random.randint(1, 100)


root = Tk()

root.title("Mack's totally advanced Number Guesser!")
root.geometry('404x300')
##root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg='black')



fontA = 'BigNoodleTitling'
fontSizeA = 20



def instructions():
    text = StringVar()
    welcomeLbl.grid_forget()
    instrButton.grid_forget()
    startButton.grid_forget()
    insL = Label(root, textvariable=text, fg='pink', bg='black').grid(row=2, pady=100)
    text.set('So you need instructions eh?')


titleLbl = Label(root)
titleLbl['borderwidth'] = (2)
titleLbl['relief'] = ('solid')
titleLbl['text'] = ("Mack's totally advanced Number Guessing Game!")
titleLbl['font'] = (fontA, fontSizeA)
titleLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)


welcomeLbl = Label(root, fg='white', bg='black')
welcomeLbl['text'] = ("Welcome Random Person")
welcomeLbl['font'] = (fontA, 30)
welcomeLbl.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)

instrButton = Button(root, command=instructions)
instrButton['text'] = ("Instructions")
instrButton['font'] = (fontA, fontSizeA)
instrButton.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=N)

startButton = Button(root, fg='red')
startButton['text'] = ("Start")
startButton['font'] = (fontA, 40)
startButton.grid(row=4,column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=E+W, pady=25)
```

Can anyone help me with setting the font and font size of my "So you need instructions Eh?"
Thanks.

Comment: You do it the same way as you did it with `titleLbl`.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? I've tried but it doesn't seem to be working. Sorry, I'm very new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a label or button, or anything really with text in it, you can define the font and font size as follows

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
label1 = Label(root, text = 'Hello' font = ('Calibri', 12))
```

When the first parameter for the 'font' function is the font name (as long as you have the font installed to your computer it should work) and the second parameter is the font size.

Comment: It's okay, I've found the problem. Thanks for the help!